# Filtering CHIRPS imageCollection by a single month for 30 years in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I need to pick the mean precipitation value for a specific month for 30 years, generate a chart for each year and display it on GEE. For example: I need to pick the January precipitation mean value for 1990, January precipitation mean value for 1991, January precipitation mean value for 1992 and so on until 2020. Then, I need to take this 30 January mean values and aggregate into a single map.

Later, I'll have to do it for the rest of the months, doing the same methodology above, getting 12 maps, each for a 30 year precipitation mean month.

I'm using the CHIRPS database for it ("UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/DAILY") and a shapefile of my own.

I tried some things and I'll link my codes below (and some codes that I found), but I don't know how to merge all the information I have to do what I need to do. (Currently new on GEE).

Links:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/cc2a24aac09f7edd7a2edd1a8e7000f4 - Monthly precipitation
https://code.earthengine.google.com/5d70943346a590d824a9847792bc05a7 - List of objects per month by year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it's a bit confusing what you are asking. But if you need to get a monthly product per year, use the following structure:

```
var january  = ee.List.sequence(0, 29).map(function(n) {
  var start = ee.Date('1990-01-01').advance(n, 'year')
  var end = start.advance(1, 'month')
  return ee.ImageCollection('UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/DAILY').filterDate(start, end)
  .select('precipitation').mean()
})
```

Add a reducer if you need to extract values from a shapefile.

**Note:** are you sure you want to extract mean precipitation from daily scenes? Consider the following normal precipitation pattern (mm/day):

- Day 1: 0
- Day 2: 0
- Day 3: 0
- Day 4: 10
- Day 5: 4
- Day 6: 0
- Day 7: 0
- Day 8: 0
- Day 9: 0
- Day 10: 0

I would compute `sum` (14 mm) instead of `mean` (1,4 mm) since precipitation should be aggregated monthly. Unless you need to compute the mean precipitation inside a polygon (use shapefile only when you are talking about storage, not representation). In that case, compute monthly sum, then extract mean for an area. That would be something like this:

```
var polygon = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
  [110.0, 0.0, 113.0, 0.0, 110.0, 3.0]
);

var january  = ee.List.sequence(0, 29).map(function(n) {
  var start = ee.Date('1990-01-01').advance(n, 'year')
  var end = start.advance(1, 'month')
  return ee.ImageCollection('UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/DAILY').filterDate(start, end)
  .select('precipitation').sum().reduceRegion({
                    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
                    geometry: polygon,
                    scale: 1000
  })
})
```

Comment: aldo_tapia, when I try to clip it to the region I want, this error happens: Line 18: january.clipToCollection is not a function. What can I do now?

Comment: @Isaac_vasconcelos `january` is a list, not an image nor image collection. There is no need to clip, the reducer is doing that process

Comment: thanks! But I still have a problem. I need this information for every pixel in the image I'm using, because I have to spacializate this data and show it in the GEE map. It means that I'll get one single map with all pixels representing the code You gave me before, the 30 years average of the sum of the monthly precipitation. Could You still help me?

Comment: @Isaac_vasconcelos in that case: `ee.ImageCollection(january)` after the first code chunk I posted for converting the list to and Image Collection. Change the reducer to `.sum()` as I recommended to you

Comment: thank You a lot, but I gotta confess that I tried it all this afternoon and wasn't succeeded. Could You share Your script with me, because I didn't get the point You're trying to tell me. I'm sorry, I'm really new in GEE and now I see I know even less I tought I knew. If You could help me one more time, I'll be very greatfull. (For your concern, I'll be studying this and other scripts that I found, untill midnight today).

Comment: @Isaac_vasconcelos sure: https://code.earthengine.google.com/e70419278667b775a1b5b393af33b13c

Comment: One more time, thank You a lot! Now I'll try to diplay this information as one map. Thanks, @aldo_tapia